# sed: what step echo's line to output with / without -n

Tags: sed

When 'sed' is invoked without the '-n' argument what buffer is printed in the following picture?  If not in this picture, can you describe what buffer is printed?  I have the same question for with the '-n' argument.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried before asking? The picture isn't really adding anything to your question; you simply seem to ask what the default behavior is with and without `-n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of `sed` is to print the pattern space after executing any script (third box from the top in the middle column in your picture). With `-n`, this default print operation is disabled. Unless there is a script which modifies the pattern space, it will contain the current input line (first box).

Read `Line 1` into pattern space. (No script present.) Print pattern space. Output: `Line 1`. Empty pattern space.

Read `Line 2` into pattern space. (No script present.) Print pattern space. Output: `Line 2`. Empty pattern space.

Etc, until reading fails because there is no more data in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The 'sed' print (implicit, or explicit with -n) will print the pattern space. From sed info page:

```
'p'
     Print the pattern space.

'P'
     Print the pattern space, up to the first <newline>.
```

Comment: The OP seems to be asking what `sed` alone, without an explicit script, will do, not how to explicitly print.